# How to exclude a directory from the code analysis?

Tags: sonarqube, code-analysis

There have been some questions about this, but none of them solves my problem.

I use SonarQube to do code analysis on one of my projects, which contain a Migrations directory. I would like to **exclude** all the source files in that directory from the code analysis.

In the projects Configuration->Settings->Exclusions->Files->Source Files Exclusions I added **"**/Migrations/*.*"**, but in the analysis results I still get issues in code files in that directory.
The directory structure of my project looks like this:  `\MyProject\Migrations\SourceFile.cs`

What am I doing wrong? Am I entering the wildcard in the wrong place, or my wildcard is wrong?

In the logs I can see

```
13:06:23.460 INFO  - Copy-paste detection exclusions:
13:06:23.476 **/Migrations/*.*
```

but then I can also see

```
13:06:12.076 INFO  - Inspecting <MyProject>\Migrations\SourceFile.cs
```

Comment: have you checked this - http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Narrowing+the+Focus

This should probably work for you:
sonar.exclusions=migrations/**/*

Comment: Yup, and that config parameter seemed to be the most logical choice, but actually a different setting parameter did the trick, details in the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had to use a different setting.

Instead of Configuration->Settings->Exclusions->**Files->Source Files Exclusions** I had to use Configuration->Settings->Exclusions->**Issues->Ignore Issues on Multiple Criteria**.

In this setting, I had to set the RULE KEY PATTERN to `*`, and I had to set the path wildcard in the FILE PATH PATTERN, `**/Migrations/.` works perfectly.

Comment: Which version of SonarQube was this for?

Comment: This was with version 4.1. I updated to the latest 5.1.1 since then, but I haven't checked if it's still working.

Answer (score 2):

That's the correct place to set it up. Please try simply `/Migrations/**` or `/MyProject/Migrations/**`. When you go to one of the issues you want to get rid of, you'll see what your "regex" path should start with.

And one more tip: **To see result, you have to rebuild the project, run sonar again.** And again, until you get it right.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I tried restarting and also simplifying the criteria, but that didn't help. However, I managed to make it work with a different config parameter, details in the answer.