# Exclude file from issues list in SonarQube

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-4.5

I'm running SonarQube 4.5 and have a project that wants to get a file excluded from the issues.  For some reason they have a few jquery libs stored with their project javascript files and aren't able to move them.  The jquery files are being analyzed and counted against the project when they shouldn't.

I can ignore them from test coverage but that doesn't remove them from issues and tech debt metrics.

Long term I'll have the team restructure their JS files but that can't be done immediately.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use source exclusions to achieve this, see this thread - [How to exclude a directory from the code analysis?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30667507/how-to-exclude-a-directory-from-the-code-analysis?noredirect=1#comment49475457_30667507)

Comment: Thanks, I had actually never seen the tabs in the general -> exclusions settings area, that took care of the need.